# Android: Google sign in with primary account only

Tags: android, google-signin, account

I'm using google sign-in in my program ... the sign in dialogue shows the accounts of the device.
My question is how can i just display the primary account without showing all the accounts?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use case for this?

Comment: I'm using this to make a time limited flavor of my paid application.
When the user first use my app it records his email and saves the time.
This doesn't work if the user logs in with another email ... The app consider him a new user and gives another trial.
Hope this is clear.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure this is the best mechanism to achieve this ... perhaps you could use some other identifier that is harder to create a second account. e.g. a verified phone number ... there is API for that: https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever